# Insert values from one table to another table and other additional values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have two tables **`Users`** and **`Friends`**. I want to copy two **`ID`** s for different users from **`Users`** table where their names already provided by C# code behind and put them into **`Friends`** table with their status column to be stored in one row at **`Friends`** table. Here is the query I made:

```
@id uniqueidentifier,
@username nvarchar(50),
@friendname nvarchar(50),
@friendstatus int
AS

INSERT INTO Friends (MYID,FriendId,ID,FriendStatus)
SELECT Users.ID,Users.ID,@id,@friendstatus
From Users cross join Friends as Friends_1
WHERE (Friends_1.MyID IN
          (SELECT ID
           FROM Users AS Users_1
           WHERE (UserName IN (@username)))) 
  AND (Friends_1.FriendId IN
          (SELECT ID
           FROM Users AS Users_1
           WHERE (UserName IN (@friendname))))
```

Comment: i have no idea what you try to do. please provide sample data (tables and parameter) and expected result. thx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
INSERT INTO Friends (MYID,FriendId,ID,FriendStatus)

SELECT Users.ID, Users.ID, @id, @friendstatus
From Users 
inner join Friends as Friends_1 ON Users.ID = Friends_1.MyID 
                                OR Users.ID = Friends_1.FriendId 
WHERE UserName IN (@username, @friendname)
```

Comment: this query didnt work but I have the feeling you could solve it with something similar to your query. I'm trying to grab the ID for user1 and put it into Friends_1.MyID and User2 with Friends_1.FriendId.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with a simple query like this:

```
insert into Friends (ID, MYID, FriendId, FriendStatus)
select 
    newid() ID,              -- you can generate a new ID in SQL Server
    -- @id ID                -- if you generate ID in your c# code: 
    u1.ID MYID, 
    u2.ID FriendId, 
    @friendstatus FriendStatus
from 
    users u1 
cross join 
    users u2
where 
    u1.UserName = @username
  and 
    u2.UserName = @friendname;
```